# Connect password protected file

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I want to connect with password protected access. Please advise as where can I pass the parameter for password in below coding.

```
With Acon1
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("V24").Value
    .Open
End With

With Rs1
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .ActiveConnection = Acon1
    .Source = "Select * from Headcount where [Employee ID]=" & myvalue0l
    .Open
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
With Acon1
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("V24").Value & _ 
";User ID=admin;Password=" 'Password
    .Open
End With
```